# How to extract value from SOAP XML response with multiple namespaces using Rest-assured?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap, rest-assured

I have the following SOAP Response returned from a call I make using Rest Assured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header>
      <epns:context xmlns:epns="http://mywebservice/v6">
         <epns:userId>SYSTEM</epns:userId>
         <epns:systemId>WEBSERVICE</epns:systemId>
         <epns:realmId />
      </epns:context>
   </env:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:liststatusResponse xmlns:ns0="http://mywebservice/v6/workflow" xmlns:asst="http://mywebservice/v6" xmlns:status="http://mywebservice/v6" xmlns:thirdparty="http://mywebservice/v6/thirdparty/v6">
         <return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="status:agreementstatus">
            <status:level>IN-PROGRESS</status:level>
            <status:nextWorkDate>2020-07-31T09:36:50+01:00</status:nextWorkDate>
            <status:type>788</status:type>
            <status:agreementNumber>89ADFGH</status:agreementNumber>
         </return>
      </ns0:liststatusResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I need to extract several values, for example`788` in  `status:type` in the first `<return...` block.

I have a test utility for checking returned values from the response:

```
@Test
public static void xmlPathTester() {
  XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(XML);
  List<String> results = xmlPath.getList("S:Envelope.S:Body.ns0:liststatusResponse.return.status:type.text()");
    for (String result : results) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

But this currently returns 1 result ~ an empty String.

It's not clear to me where I am going wrong.

Comment: XML you provided throws an error

Comment: @Fenio thanks, indeed it was.  However, now fixed and a proper Response is received yet I am still unable to obtain the `<status:type>` attribute of `789`

Comment: I still get XML parse error when I paste given XML to my code

Comment: @Fenio apologies :( now fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use XmlPath, don't provide namespaces.

```
XmlPath path = XmlPath.from(xml);
    path.getList("Envelope.Body.liststatusResponse.return.type.text()").forEach(System.out::println);
```

This code returns:

```
788
```

In order to declare namespaces you have to make XmlPath namespace aware as per [documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#xml-namespaces):

```
given().
        config(RestAssured.config().xmlConfig(xmlConfig().with().namespaceAware(true))).
when().
         get("/package-db-xml").
then().
         body(hasXPath("/db:package-database", namespaceContext));
```

and since you have multiple namespaces I would just use non-namespace XmlPath